# Why my worker node fails after submitting topology?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, apache-storm

Here is my minimal Multi container (storm 1.1.0) setup on Kubernetes on Azure using Azure container service
- 1 zookeeper container
- 1 nimbus container (UI is running on the same container)
- 1 worker container

All containers are connected properly,can see that in the Storm UI and zookeeper logs.

But When I deploy the test topology - worker node fails (supervisor process waits for worker to start and restarts).Seems like worker process is not started by supervisor.

Here is my storm.yaml config for the worker node:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
   - "10.0.xx.xxx"

 storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

 nimbus.seeds: ["10.0.xxx.xxx"]

 storm.local.dir: "/storm/datadir"
```

Could you please help me out ?

Comment: Kindly provide the error messages that you get when your topology fails. It can help in resolving the issue.

Comment: I can't find error logs though. Found a temporary solution: Updated worker container's /etc/hosts/ file to include nimbus & zookeeper containers hostname mapping as described in http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.0/Troubleshooting.html ---- Worker processes crash on startup without any stack trace